# A variation on NIM game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

**Problem:** We have two heaps of coins with 100 and 99 coins. Two players take some coins alternately, either at least one, at most 10, from the first one, or at least one, at most 9 from the second. The winner is who takes the last coin. How shall the game be played to win?

I think this is supposed to be solve using NIM strategy and Grundy numbers. Some hints on what general strategy to use on these problems would be nice. Also, an in-depth analysis of the problem would be helpful as a model that would allow me to approach other similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Start by computing the Grundy numbers for each heap individually.  There are simple related formulas for them.  Then you want the Grundy numbers of the two heaps to be equal so they sum to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

First compute the Grundy number, using the mex formula, for the heap of size $n$ and moves 1 to 10. This is a recursive process, which is periodic (in this case) with period 11: $\operatorname{mex}(n)=n \pmod{11}$.

Then for the heap with moves $1$ to $9$ we get a period of $10$ and
values $\operatorname{mex}(n)=n \pmod{10}$.

It's simple to write a small program to do this, or make a table by hand.

So $\operatorname{mex}(100)=1$ for the first heap and $\operatorname{mex}(99)=9$ for the second. So the first player wins by making the value of the first heap $9$ (moving to $97$) so that the total value is $0$ (this is a xor-sum of heaps, recall) or by making the second heap value $1$, by moving to $91$...

Comment: If the first pile is periodic with period $11$, why is $12$ equivalent to $2$?  It should be $1$.  If you move to $(98,99)$ I move to $(97,99)$ and claim I will win.

Comment: @RossMillikan it's periodic from $11$ onwards, so $11 \equiv 22$ and $12 \equiv 23$ etc.

Comment: No, it is periodic from the start, so $12 \equiv 1$.  Let us play the first pile starting with $12$.  I take $1$, not $2$, and win.  Similarly for the second pile.  The numbers are just the number of stones mod $11$ for the first pile and mod $10$ for the second.

Comment: @RossMillikan and I said the Grundy value of $12$ is $2$ not that $12$ and $2$ are equivalent.

Comment: OK, then lets play $(12,2)$, which you claim is a P position.  I move to $(2,2)$ and win.  I claim $(12,1)$ is a P position.  Your move?

Comment: @RossMillikan Oops, I first miscalculated the initial values in my program; now it's correct I believe.

Comment: Yes, this is now correct

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Ross Millikan, To make xor of grundy numbers = 0, should I have to change only 1 bit in binary representation of one grundy number or more than one bit is allowed because we can make always make xor of grundy numbers = 0 if modification of more than 1 bit is allowed by making both values equal. right ? In that case, both players can always win in any game. right ?

Comment: @ankit no. This is a partisan game so we know mathematically that in each position the moving player either always can win or will always lose (against optimal play). Nothing to do with binary representation of numbers.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma,Thanks! can you please tell me,for a particular game with the fixed no. of minimum and maximum number of coins like in the above problem,can we say that when a player 2 can win or when a player 1 can win ? does zero or non-zero values of xor of grundy numbers of each pile say something regarding it? If we have only 1 pile with total coins 'n' and min=1 and max=m coins a person can remove then if n % (1+m) >= 1 && n % (1+m) <= m then player 1 will win and if n % (1+m) >= 0 && n % (1+m) < 1 then player 2 will win if player 1 has started the game.Like this can we say anything here?

Comment: @ankit You compute the Grundy number of the total game and if it's 0 player 2 wins, if not player 1 wins. That's just the general theory. This holds for any position. Do it for the start position and you know the value of the game. The 100/99 game under the given rules is a first player win, as said.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thank you !